# How to pass json Data that obtained from rest api from controller to view?

Tags: c#, json, rest, model-view-controller, jsonresult

I made a wcf Rest sevice and i called service using my mvc application, Rest sevice is working properly and getting json data through url **(http://localhost:56299/RestService.svc/List)** using HttpClient class, but unable to access that data in controller and pass to view.

*Code :-*

```
{
 *string apiurl = "http://localhost:56299/RestService.svc/List";

HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

client.BaseAddress = new Uri(apiurl);

 client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));


HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(apiurl);

var users = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;

var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(users);*
}
```

I sucessfully obtained data in var obj in json format but further i am unable to returned json data in variable obj how i will use that?

Comment: You have to create model view, deserialize json data to this model and pass it to your view. Show json structure to help you better

Comment: I did that , but doing that way it return only one record and attribute's value is null but in users have multiple record

Comment: Json Structure  {"GetAllUserResult":[{"City":"Pune","Name":"Ranjeet","id":1},{"City":"Mumbai","Name":"Amit","id":2},{"City":"jaipur","Name":"Nitesh","id":3},{"City":"bkn","Name":"Mohit","id":5}]}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the below code line, deserializes your json string to `object`.

```
var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(users);
```

Rather you should deserialize it to a specific model or object and send that as mode to your view like (assuming you will have a class defined named `User` which matches the returned JSON structure)

```
var model = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<User>(users); 
return view(model);
```

Per your posted JSON structure `{"City":"bkn","Name‌​":"Mohit","id":5}` you should create a model as below

```
public class User
{
  [jsonProperty(Name="Id")]
  public int id {get; set;}
  public string Name {get; set;}
  public string City {get; set;}
}
```

Then you can deserialize it to `IEnumerable<User>`

```
var model = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<User>>(users); 
return view(model);
```

Comment: still i not getting all records because this way i it return only one record

Comment: @niteshkumarmodi, install `json.net` from NuGet and put some self effort and search this things in internet

Answer (score 0):

For solving this problem the main issue was name of object that is declared in model to access json.

Json Structure **{"GetAllUserResult":[{"City":"Pune","Name":"Ranjeet","id":1}‌​]}**

For this I made a List type of User which is model class, named as GetAllUserResult which is name of my json structue that holding all data.

```
public List<User> GetAllUserResult { get; set; }
```

After that i deserialized json structure using model object

```
var users = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;

User obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<User>(users);
```

And access data using

```
 obj.GetAllUserResult[i].Id;  // i is index
```

and get that data in list and pass to view

Answer (score 0):

this is my way. You can consult

**Class model**

```
public class CheckStatusModel
{
    public int OBJID { get; set; }
    public string SUPID { get; set; }
    public string STATUSPTC { get; set; }  
    public int DATEACTIVESUP { get; set; }
}

  public class CheckStatus
{
    public List<CheckStatusModel> Data { get; set; } // data is an array so this needs to be some kind of collection
    public string StatusCode { get; set; }
}
```

**Sending request to find web api REST service resource using
HttpClient****

```
using (var client = new HttpClient())
{
     client.BaseAddress = new Uri(Baseurl);
     client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Clear();
     client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new 
     MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
     HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsJsonAsync("api/RPDeployment/BIL_CFP_BOX_CHECK_STATUSPTC", checkStatusParam);
     if(response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
       {
            var EmpResponse = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
            ListStatusPTC = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<CheckStatus>(EmpResponse); // the JSON contains an object, so this needs to deserialize to an object. you can't deserialize to a list.

       }
 }
```